# HttpResponse execute works only on Android API 8 and API 10

Tags: android, httprequest

I have an xml parser that works well on Android api 8 and 10 in emulator (I have api 10 on my device and also works great) but tried emulating higher api and gives me error on the http request. Here is the Parser.class:

```
package com.muc.horoscop;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.BasicScheme;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.util.Log;

public class XMLParser {


public XMLParser() {

}

/**
 * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
 * @param url string
 * */


public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = new String();

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

//          httpPost.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(
//          new UsernamePasswordCredentials("client_ro", "+_lklklkl*/544pF"),"UTF-8", false));  


        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}

/**
 * Getting XML DOM element
 * @param XML string
 * */
public Document getDomElement(String xml){
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
}

/** Getting node value
  * @param elem element
  */
 public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
     Node child;
     if( elem != null){
         if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
             for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                 if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                     return child.getNodeValue();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     return "";
 }

 /**
  * Getting node value
  * @param Element node
  * @param key string
  * */
 public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }
}
```

Here is the LogCat

```
12-31 11:23:31.223: D/AndroidRuntime(442): Shutting down VM
12-31 11:23:31.223: W/dalvikvm(442): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
12-31 11:23:31.243: E/AndroidRuntime(442): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-31 11:23:31.243: E/AndroidRuntime(442): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.muc.horoscop/com.muc.horoscop.AfisareHoroscop}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
12-31 11:23:31.243: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
12-31 11:23:31.243: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
12-31 11:23:31.243: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
12-31 11:23:31.243: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
12-31 11:23:31.243: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-31 11:23:31.243: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
12-31 11:23:31.243: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
12-31 11:23:31.243: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-31 11:23:31.243: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
12-31 11:23:31.243: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
12-31 11:23:31.243: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
12-31 11:23:31.243: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-31 11:23:31.243: E/AndroidRuntime(442): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
12-31 11:23:31.243: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1077)
12-31 11:23:31.243: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:477)
12-31 11:23:31.243: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:277)
12-31 11:23:31.243: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:249)
12-31 11:23:31.243: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
12-31 11:23:31.243: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
12-31 11:23:31.243: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
12-31 11:23:31.243: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
12-31 11:23:31.243: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
12-31 11:23:31.243: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
12-31 11:23:31.243: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
12-31 11:23:31.243: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at com.muc.horoscop.XMLParser.getXmlFromUrl(XMLParser.java:52)
12-31 11:23:31.243: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at com.muc.horoscop.AfisareHoroscop.onCreate(AfisareHoroscop.java:111)
12-31 11:23:31.243: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
12-31 11:23:31.243: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
12-31 11:23:31.243: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
12-31 11:23:31.243: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  ... 11 more
```

And the activity class where the list is created:

```
public class AfisareHoroscop extends ListActivity {


    static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_DATA = "data";
    static final String KEY_SCURT = "scurt";
    static final String KEY_DESC = "descriere";

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
    }

    public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

        final String lala = getSharedPreferences("zodialui", MODE_PRIVATE).getString("zodia_consumator", "");
        final String url = "http://calina.mucomputers.eu/"+lala+".xml";
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_afisare_horoscop);
        //afisare titlu
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);
        final String tit_gen = getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.titlu_gen);
        final TextView myTitleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titlu);
        String titlul = new String(tit_gen+" "+lala);
        SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(titlul);
        spanString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, spanString.length(), 0);
        myTitleText.setText(spanString);
        ImageView semn_titlu = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        if (lala.equals("Balanta")) {
            semn_titlu.setImageResource(R.drawable.balanta);
        }else if (lala.equals("Berbec")){
            semn_titlu.setImageResource(R.drawable.berbec);
        }else if (lala.equals("Capricorn")){
            semn_titlu.setImageResource(R.drawable.capricorn);
        }else if (lala.equals("Fecioara")){
            semn_titlu.setImageResource(R.drawable.fecioara);
        }else if (lala.equals("Gemeni")){
            semn_titlu.setImageResource(R.drawable.gemeni);
        }else if (lala.equals("Leu")){
            semn_titlu.setImageResource(R.drawable.leu);
        }else if (lala.equals("Pesti")){
            semn_titlu.setImageResource(R.drawable.pesti);
        }else if (lala.equals("Rac")){
            semn_titlu.setImageResource(R.drawable.rac);
        }else if (lala.equals("Sagetator")){
            semn_titlu.setImageResource(R.drawable.sagetator);
        }else if (lala.equals("Scorpion")){
            semn_titlu.setImageResource(R.drawable.scorpion);
        }else if (lala.equals("Taur")){
            semn_titlu.setImageResource(R.drawable.taur);
        }else if (lala.equals("Varsator")){
            semn_titlu.setImageResource(R.drawable.varsator);
        }
        //afisare titlu

        if (isOnline() == true) {

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(url); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_DATA, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DATA));
            map.put(KEY_SCURT, parser.getValue(e, KEY_SCURT));
            map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);
        }

        // Adding menuItems to ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { KEY_SCURT, KEY_DATA, KEY_DESC }, new int[] {
                        R.id.scurt, R.id.data, R.id.descriere });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
        Collections.reverse(menuItems);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();


        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem

                String scurt = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.scurt)).getText().toString();
                String data = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.data)).getText().toString();
                String descriere = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.descriere)).getText().toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(KEY_SCURT, scurt);
                in.putExtra(KEY_DATA, data);

                in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, descriere);
                startActivity(in);

            }

        });
        } else {

            Button btn = new Button(this);
            View.OnClickListener myhandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(AfisareHoroscop.this, AfisareHoroscop.class);  //your class
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
              };
              btn.setOnClickListener(myhandler);
            btn.setText("Refresh");
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsd = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            paramsd.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
            paramsd.height = 60;
            paramsd.width = 60;
            btn.setLayoutParams(paramsd);
            addContentView(btn,paramsd); 
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            String no_con = getResources().getString(R.string.no_connection);
            CharSequence text = no_con;
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_afisare_horoscop, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_settings:
            Intent menu_set = new Intent (this, MainActivity.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(menu_set);
        return true;
        case R.id.menu_despre:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, DespreActivity.class));
        return true;
        default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

I spent 2 days to find out what's happening, that's maybe because i'm a beginner.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two Solution of this Problem but first one is great solution.

1) Don't write network call in Main UI Thread, Use Async Task for that.

2) Write below code into your MainActivity file after setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); but this is not proper way.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

And below import statement into your java file.

```
import android.os.StrictMode;
```

And see below link for more information.

[Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136539/caused-by-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: The second one works, even if my min sdk was 8 i modified it to 9 and it works. The first one will take me a little longer to try it since i have to learn Async Task. Thank you!!!