# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadExceptio

Tags: android, web-services, networking

in my app i call a webservice..... and it shows some error. the error is given below..

```
 04-26 10:00:53.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1600): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 04-26 10:00:53.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1600): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
 04-26 10:00:53.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
 04-26 10:00:53.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
 04-26 10:00:53.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
 04-26 10:00:53.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
 04-26 10:00:53.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
 04-26 10:00:53.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
 04-26 10:00:53.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
 04-26 10:00:53.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
 04-26 10:00:53.682: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
```

i call the web service as given below....

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPostReq = new HttpPost(serverURL+url);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
StringEntity se = null;

try {
    String jSonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
    se = new StringEntity(jSonString);
    se.setContentType("application/json");
    httpPostReq.setEntity(se);
    httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPostReq);
    HttpEntity resultEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    inputStream=resultEntity.getContent();
    resultString = convertStreamToString(inputStream);
    Log.e("result",resultString);
}
```

but this one is working on the emulator.... but not working with device.. i test this using a wi-fi connected tablet... but its not working.....  pls help.....me......

Comment: This exception is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread. Run your code in AsyncTask

Comment: is that new thats for jellybean right because it doesnt matter earlier right?

Comment: @JRowan this exception is shown from honeycomb onwards,It allows to work on earlier version(before honeycomb)

Comment: @Abhilash, thanks i just wanted to get that straight

Comment: ya am ruuning this code on ma sync task......

Comment: check this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136539/caused-by-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception
hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

You should use [AyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, String> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPostReq = new HttpPost(urls[0]);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    StringEntity se = null;

    try {
        String jSonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
        se = new StringEntity(jSonString);
        se.setContentType("application/json");
        httpPostReq.setEntity(se);
        httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPostReq);
        HttpEntity resultEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        inputStream=resultEntity.getContent();
        resultString = convertStreamToString(inputStream);
        Log.e("result",resultString);
        }
         return resultString;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     // progress
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
     // result
 }
}
```

use like

```
 new MyTask().execute(serverURL+url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code It will help,

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: It may work but that a very bad practice I wouldn't recommend. The exception was added to prevent what you are suggesting in the first place. <br>AsyncTasks are here for it.